# Can't to get Button script from gameobject in unity

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have some button in my game and i want when host player answers and choose one button to get the button script of this game object button to change its color.

But i get some error like that :

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

This is my code :

```
Button playerOneAnswerBtn = GameObject.FindWithTag (playerOneAnswer).GetComponent<Button> ();
ColorBlock cbPlayerOneAnswer = playerOneAnswerBtn.colors;
cbPlayerOneAnswer.normalColor = Color.blue;
cbPlayerOneAnswer.highlightedColor = Color.blue;
playerOneAnswerBtn.colors = cbPlayerOneAnswer;
```

Comment: `Debug.Log()` the result of `FindWithTag()` and `GetComponent<Button>()`. Find out where the null reference is, and debug from there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new to programming you should need to keep in mind the meaning of [NullReferenceException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx) 
A NullReferenceException occurs when you try to use a method or property of a reference type (C#, Visual Basic) whose value is null. ([more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxw2ez55.aspx))
So in your case there is object missing/null and you try to access it. Most probably this line

```
  Button playerOneAnswerBtn = GameObject.FindWithTag (playerOneAnswer).GetComponent<Button> ();
```

You can ensure it through

```
if(GameObject.FindWithTag (playerOneAnswer)! = null){
    //your code
}
else{
    Debug.LogError(playerOneAnswer +" tag object did not found.")
}
```